# Performance and reliability of np.intersect1d vs masks

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, slice

I'm using numpy to work with a time series that has a number of bad_values=-9999.0 . For example:

vals = [3., 352., -32.0e-3, -9999.0, 35., -9999.0]

I have a number of different conditions that the values must meet to be acceptable in my condition. One such cut could be all my values must be greater than 30. What is the most appropriate way to go about combining this *>30* condition with *bad_value* condition?

I can see two possibilities:

1) using masks:

```
g_vals_mask = (vals > 30.)
bv_mask = (vals > bad_val)
mask = bv_mask*g_vals_mask

idxs = np.where(mask)[0]

cut_vals=vals[idxs]
```

2) intersect idx lists:

```
g_idxs=np.where(vals>30.)
bv_idx=np.where(vals>-9999.0)

idxs=np.intersect1d(g_idx, bv_idx)

cut_vals=vals[idxs]
```

I make repeated calculations combining many different types of *vals*, each with different bad_vals. Is one version of this a better practice than the other? Is one more efficient or robust?

### Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need two masks? Isn't `vals > 30` sufficient since `30 > -9999.0`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is one dimensional, you could use the mask directly in the slicing of values:

```
import numpy as np
cut_vals=vals[np.logical_and(vals > 30, vals > bad_val)]
```

Seems like a small improvement in performance compared with the methods you proposed. The intersect was a order of magnitude slower than the mask methods.

```
# Average timing
# Masks:
# 0.309858489037
# Masks2:
# 0.351503372192
# Intersect:
# 2.1616836071

import numpy as np
import timeit as it
vals = np.random.rand(1000)

def masks2():
    return vals[np.logical_and(vals > 0.7, vals > 0.1)]

# 1) using masks:
def masks():
    g_vals_mask = (vals > 0.7)
    bv_mask = (vals > 0.1)
    mask = bv_mask*g_vals_mask

    idxs = np.where(mask)[0]

    return vals[idxs]

# 2) intersect idx lists:
def intersect():
    g_idx=np.where(vals>0.7)
    bv_idx=np.where(vals>0.1)

    idxs=np.intersect1d(g_idx, bv_idx)

    return vals[idxs]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    reps = 10
    number_iter = 10000
    print 'Masks:'
    print np.average(
        np.array(it.repeat("masks()", setup="from __main__ import masks", repeat = reps, number = number_iter))
    )
    print 'Masks2:'
    print np.average(
        np.array(it.repeat("masks2()", setup="from __main__ import masks2", repeat = reps, number = number_iter))
    )
    print 'Intersect:'
    print np.average(
        np.array(it.repeat("intersect()", setup="from __main__ import intersect", repeat = reps, number = number_iter))
    )
```